# IP Allowlisting from bitbucket to AWS Amplify

Tags: bitbucket, aws-amplify

We have enable IP allow listing feature in bitbucket and we added our internal VPN IP's. Now It's failing to talk to AWS amplify while cloning the repo during deployment process. Any possible ways to resolve this.

Error message:

````
To access this repository, an admin must whitelist your IP.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. 
[ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Unable to clone repository due to user error code: 128```
````